# how a function getw() worked, when stream is stdin?

Tags: c, user-input, stdin, glibc

I wonder how getw() function worked, when stream is stdin.

== My Cricumstances==

In windows 10(Visual Studio 2017 community),

Virtual Machine Ubuntu 16.04,

docker in VM.

glibc version is 2.23 in unix-like

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a = getw(stdin);
    printf("%c\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

When I press '3' on keyboard, then Enter, I expect same character what I inputted.

But it seems that a.out binary needs another input.

when I press '3',[enter],'4', it output 3

when I press '34', it needs another input.

when I press '123' it output 1.

Comment: 123 and linefeed char makes 4 chars, needed to scan an integer in binary form

Answer (score 2):

[`getw`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getw.3.html) is not really suitable for standard interactive input. It is used to read integers from *binary* data (and provided for compatiblity purposes, now everyone uses `fread`).

In your system `int` needs 4 bytes, that's why the function reads 4 characters (including *return* aka linefeed), then returns its result.

But the result you're printing is truncated because of wrong format specifier (`%c` instead of `%d`)

For instance if I enter (with return):

```
aaa
```

I get a value of `a` which depends on the endianness of the machine (and the size of `int` but let's suppose it's 4)

If I use `%x` to print it, it prints

```
0xa616161
```

which we recognize as linefeed plus 3 `a` characters (reverted byte order because of my little endian machine).

If you want to scan an integer from user input, just use `scanf("%d",&a);`

Comment: thanks, your reply is very helpful.
I'm working on making user input function list in glibc_2.23, so that's why I posted my question.

Comment: @rivmt yea, that is definitely not an "user input function" unless user speaks binary

Comment: After reading the [glibc implementation of getw](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/stdio-common/getw.c.html) it becomes pretty clear how it works. It just reads an `int` from the stream.